# Active noise cancellation on speakers

Tags: software, active-noise-control

I was wondering if it is possible cancel out my voice during a phone call using active noise cancellation for people around me. The speakers of my phone could reproduce the signal recorded from my own voice and invert the phase. Would this cancel out my voice for people around me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not an audio production or sound design question. it could be answerred here, however it seems off topic to me because the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The system couldn't compensate for time differences, especially for multiple other listeners.

Noise canceling headphones work because they are so close to your ears that the microphone is picking up almost what you would hear otherwise, and they only have to compensate for one listening position.